# Unexpected output in concurrent file writing in java web

Tags: java, multithreading, file, web, concurrency

I wrote a very simple Java web application ,just included some basic function like register , sign in , changing the password and some others.

I don't use database. I just create a file in the app to record the users' information and do the database stuff.

I used JMeter to stressing the web application, especially the register interface.
The JMeter shows that the result of the 1000 thread is right
[image]
 but when I look into the information.txt , which stores the users' information, it's wrong because it stores 700+ record :
[image]

but it should include 1000 record, it must be somewhere wrong

I use the singleton class to do the write/read stuff, and i add a synchronized word to the class, the insert() function which is used by register to record the register information is shown as below: (a part of it)

```
public class Database {

private static Database database = null;
private static File file = null;


public synchronized static Database getInstance() {

    if (database == null) {
        database = new Database();
    }

    return database;
}


private Database() {

    String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/")
            .getPath() + "information.txt";
    file = new File(path);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
public void insert(String account, String password, String username) {

    RandomAccessFile infoFile = null;

    try {
        infoFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        String record;
        long offset = 0;

        while ((record = infoFile.readLine()) != null ) {
            offset += record.getBytes().length+2;
        }

        infoFile.seek(offset);
        record = account+"|"+password+"|"+username+"\r\n";
        infoFile.write(record.getBytes());
        infoFile.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (infoFile != null) {
            try {
                infoFile.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

the question is why would this happened , the synchronized is thread safe, why i lost so many data and some blank line was inserted into it, what could I do the correct it !

Comment: Synchronized is used to get the lock of the object. You are using `synchronized` for a method which returns you the object, now since there is no object at time of calling `getInstance()` (apart from the global class level lock) so there is no point of synchronizing `getInstance()`. You should better be synchronizing your insert method.

Comment: @hagrawal thanks! I get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are synchronizing the getInstance() method, but not the insert() method. This makes the retrieval of the instance of Database thread-safe, but not the write operation.